# HTML jump to another place on page doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem. The title speaks for itself. Sample code:

```
<a href="#test1">Go to test 1</a>
<a href="#test2">Go to test 2</a>
<a href="#test3">Go to test 3</a>
<a href="#test4">Go to test 4</a>
<a href="#test5">Go to test 5</a>
<a href="#test6">Go to test 6</a>
<a href="#test7">Go to test 7</a>
<a href="#test8">Go to test 8</a>

<div id="test1">Some text for test 1</div>
<div id="test2">Some text for test 2</div>
<div id="test3">Some text for test 3</div>
<div id="test4">Some text for test 4</div>
<div id="test5">Some text for test 5</div>
<div id="test6">Some text for test 6</div>
<div id="test7">Some text for test 7</div>
<div id="test8">Some text for test 8</div>
```

Of course this is just an example and my page is much longer so "jumping" is more visible.
This code doesn't work (at least to me). It only adds a #test to the link, but doesn't jump. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.
And sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

Edit: Okay, on my website with such a link I wanted to move to a div located higher than the link, and it did not work, now I moved it lower and it works. But is it possible for such a link to move to a higher placed div?

Comment: Your *href* path needs to match id of the element you want to jump to

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to change here, everything is fine on my website. 
So the problem is not resolved yet.

Comment: This is a pretty simple function. There must be more to this, is there anything else you can provide?

Comment: What browser are you using? You may need a fix in some cases

Comment: Please check out the post edit

Comment: Yes, it will scroll up to a div higher on the page is there is room for it to scroll.

Answer (score 3):

@Sean, thanks for the correction

The page isn't "jumping" anywhere as the page isn't long enough to scroll.

If you add a `margin-bottom` to the elements to make the content not all visible immediately, you will see that the page does "jump", please see this code snippet for a demonstration.

```css
a, div{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<a href="#test1">Go to test 1</a>
<a href="#test2">Go to test 2</a>
<a href="#test3">Go to test 3</a>
<a href="#test4">Go to test 4</a>
<a href="#test5">Go to test 5</a>
<a href="#test6">Go to test 6</a>
<a href="#test7">Go to test 7</a>
<a href="#test8">Go to test 8</a>

<div id="test1">Some text for test 1</div>
<div id="test2">Some text for test 2</div>
<div id="test3">Some text for test 3</div>
<div id="test4">Some text for test 4</div>
<div id="test5">Some text for test 5</div>
<div id="test6">Some text for test 6</div>
<div id="test7">Some text for test 7</div>
<div id="test8">Some text for test 8</div>
```

Comment: This is almost correct. The page in the question isn't scrolling because the page isn't long enough to scroll. Even if something is already in the viewport, the browser will still scroll until it's at the very top, provided there is enough page left to afford the scroll.

Comment: I know that everything is visible at once, so I wrote that mine is much longer and a scrolling is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The page isn't scrolling because the page isn't long enough to scroll at all. If you increase the height of the page, it works.

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<a href="#test1">Go to test 1</a>
<a href="#test2">Go to test 2</a>
<a href="#test3">Go to test 3</a>
<a href="#test4">Go to test 4</a>
<a href="#test5">Go to test 5</a>
<a href="#test6">Go to test 6</a>
<a href="#test7">Go to test 7</a>
<a href="#test8">Go to test 8</a>

<div id="test1">Some text for test 1</div>
<div id="test2">Some text for test 2</div>
<div id="test3">Some text for test 3</div>
<div id="test4">Some text for test 4</div>
<div id="test5">Some text for test 5</div>
<div id="test6">Some text for test 6</div>
<div id="test7">Some text for test 7</div>
<div id="test8">Some text for test 8</div>
```